# Search different words in file with AND parameter in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this file

```
global_begin;
index_assign;tgtindex
gloabal_end;
test_start;
1a;1b;
test_end;
```

At first a must check if the string global_begin **and** global_end is in the file. But it doesnt work then the string **globsal_begin** is in the file.

```
if 'global_begin' and 'global_end' in config.read():
    print('both params ok')
else:
    print('error')
```

what is my error with the and?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do two searches like that with the AND keyword so you would need to do something like this.

```py
content = config.read()

if 'global_begin' in content and 'global_end' in content:
    print('both params ok')
else:
    print('error')
```